# How does srand() work?

Tags: c, random, srand

This is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
int main(){
float m, n;
printf("Enter n, m:");
scanf("%f %f", &n, &m);
int l;
l=m-n;
int i;
for(i=0; i<4; i++){
    srand(time(NULL));
    double r=rand();
    r/=RAND_MAX;
    r*=l;
    r+=n;
    printf("%f ", r);
}
return 0;
}
```

Why it generates same numbers? and when I write `srand(time(NULL));`before the loop it generates different numbers! why it is like this? how does this program work?

Comment: Have you tried `man srand` or even google?

Comment: `time(NULL)` is likely to give you the same value for every iteration of your loop (since it is seconds granularity). So you are seeding with the same value and resetting the `rand` sequence with each `srand` call. There is no need to continuously call `srand`.

Comment: @kaylum You've answered a different question. OP is asking why `srand()` changes the number sequence.

Comment: @John3136 I guess I was addressing "Why it generates the same number?". The reason is because `srand` resets the sequence every time it is called. So with the same seed the `rand` sequence will be the same each time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call to `time(NULL)` returns the current calendar time (seconds since Jan 1, 1970).
So its the same seed you are giving. So, rand gives the same value.

Simply you may use:

```
 srand (time(NULL)+i);
```

Answer (score 5):

`srand()` *seeds* the random number sequence.

> The `srand` function uses the argument as a seed for a new sequence of pseudo-random numbers to be returned by subsequent calls to `rand`. **If `srand` is then called with the same seed value, the sequence of pseudo-random numbers shall be repeated.** ...  C11dr §7.22.2.2 2

And `time()` is typically the same value - for a second  [@kaylum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33250156/how-does-srand-work#comment54302363_33250156)

[Edit]

Better to call `srand()` only once early in the code

```
int main(void) {
  srand((unsigned) time(NULL));
  ...
```

or, if you want the same sequence every time, do not call `srand()` at all - useful for debugging.

```
int main(void) {
  // If code is not debugging, then seed the random number generator.
  #ifdef NDEBUG
    srand((unsigned) time(NULL));
  #endif
  ...
```