# random value is not the same in the txt file

Tags: c

I'm creating a sales project for a specific product in c. What happens is that each customer is required to register to have a customer number, but I have a problem because the program manages the number, but when it goes to save it in the txt file, it doesn't give the correct one. However I'm having another problem with the client's name, if I write the full name it gives an error. How can I solve these problems? Thanks

This is my code:

```
 #include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct client CLIENT;

struct client {
    char name[80];
    char country[10];
    int tin;
};

void createprofile() {
    char tin_present;
    int i;
    
    
    FILE* bd;
    bd = fopen("bd.txt", "a+");
    CLIENT c;


    printf("\t *** Create customer profile *** \n");

    printf("Client code: ");

    for (i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
        printf("%d\n ", rand() % 1000000); 
    }

    printf("Type your name: ");
    scanf("%s", &c.name);

    printf("TIN present?? ");
    scanf("%s", &tin_present);
    if (tin_present == 's' || tin_present == 'S') {
        while (1) {
            printf("\n\tEnter your TIN: ");
            scanf("%d", &c.tin);

            if (c.tin >= 999999999) {
                printf("\tNumber with more than 9 digits is not allowed. Please try again.");

            } else if (c.tin <= 99999999) {

                printf("\tNumber with less than 9 digits is not allowed. Please try again.");
            } else
                break;
        }
        printf("\tValid.\n");
    } else {
        printf("TIN not entered\n");
    }

    printf("What is your country? ");
    scanf("%s", &c.country);

    fprintf(bd, "code: %d | name: %s | tin: %i | country: %s \n", c.name, c.tin, c.country);
    fclose(bd);
}
```

Comment: Why do you have a while loop that only runs one iteration?

Comment: You're not saving the client code in a variable, you're just printing it.

Comment: You can't use `%s` to read into a `char` variable, it's for reading strings. Use `%c` for a single character.

Comment: In the `fprintf()` you have no argument for `code: %d`.

Comment: Have you called `srand()` somewhere?

Comment: Your only `rand` call result is discarded (well, it is printed too, but not to file for sure)

Comment: @Barmar well, the while loop loops until number in a specific range. Was code edited since you asked that?

Comment: @GarrGodfrey `for (i = 0; i < 1; i++) {` - still there

Comment: @EugeneSh.  ok, I was thrown by calling a `for` loop a `while`....

Comment: In the line `fprintf(bd, "code: %d | name: %s | tin: %i | country: %s \n", c.name, c.tin, c.country);`, there are 4 format specifiers, but only 3 arguments.   The compiler should warn you about that.

Comment: @Ana - please be sure to "upvote" and/or "accept" one of the replies below if you found them helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Add client code member to struct, i.e. `int client_code;`

Then consider changing this:

```
for (i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
    printf("%d\n ", rand() % 1000000); 
}
```

To this:

```
c.client_code = rand() % 1000000;
printf("Client Code: %d\n ", c.client_code);
```

Note on using `rand()`.   If not already done, (in the code you have not shown) [srand()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33250355/645128) should be called early in your program, one time only, *Prior* to calling `rand()`, to ensure that your pseudo-random values are truly pseudo-random.  (The link provides examples how.)

Then in your file output, add client code:

```
fprintf(bd, "code: %d | name: %s | tin: %i | country: %s \n", c.client_code, c.name, c.tin, c.country);
```

Other suggestions might include either using an array of struct to contain more than one client

```
#define MAX_CUSTOMERS 100 //or what makes sense for your need

typedef struct {
    char name[80];
    char country[10];
    int tin;
    int client_code;
}CLIENT_s;

CLIENT_s client[MAX_CUSTOMERS];
```

...or use [Linked Lists](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/linked-list-set-1-introduction/) in which to read your client file, add, delete clients, then update file.

Comment: @Eugene Sh - Thanks for the edit.

Comment: Don't forget to remind the OP to call [srand()](https://linux.die.net/man/3/rand) (e.g. `srand(time(0));`), and to call it exactly once in the program (before calling rand()).

Comment: @paulsm4 - I did this in the comments under O Post, but will add it here as well.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

1. For the random number problem, as [ryyker](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70384777/17695950) already commented, the problem is that you're not storing your created number anywhere, you're just printing it.

You can do as [ryyker](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70384777/17695950) suggested:

- Create a new "info" inside your CLIENT object, where you can store the value of client-id. Consider changing this:

```cpp
typedef struct client CLIENT;

struct client {
    char name[80];
    char country[10];
    int tin;
};
```

To this:

```cpp
/*    If you want to, you can do this, change your struct prototype
and condense it into the struct declaration    */

typedef struct client {
    char name[80];
    char country[10];
    int tin;
    int client_code; // or any other variable name your prefer to
} CLIENT; // and condensing, you write here the struct shortcut/typedef-name
```

- As [@paulsm4](https://stackoverflow.com/users/421195/paulsm4) reinforced, you're not setting the `rand()` seed nowhere in your code, so you should set it once, earlier in the program using `srand()`:

```cpp
srand(0);
```

- Now, you can store the generated value inside your client information. Consider changing this:

```cpp
for(i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
    printf("%d", rand() % 1000000);
}
```

Into this (note that as already commented before, there's no need to use this `for` with just one iteration):

```cpp
c.client_code = rand() % 1000000;
```

- And then add the new value into your `bd.txt` file:

```cpp
fprintf(bd, "code: %d | name: %s | tin: %i | country: %s \n", c.client_code, c.name, c.tin, c.country);
```

---

2. For client's name, I guess the problem you're having maybe is on the `scanf` function.

-> In C, vectors are treated as pointers. This being said, when you write the vector's name in some place of your program, what the program receives is the memory address of the first position of the vector.

-> A string is a vector of chars, so we'll not use the `&` (passes memory address of a variable) in `scanf`, 'cause its name is already a pointer.

Then, consider making this change:

```
printf("Type your name: ");
scanf("%s", &c.name);
```

To this (the same applies to your **country scanning)**:

```
printf("Type your name: ");
scanf("%s", c.name); // without the '&'
```

OBS: if you want to read a string/fullname with spaces, you should use this format for `scanf`:

```
printf("Type your name: ");
scanf("%[^\n]s", c.name); // [^\n] tells to the program to ignore newline characters until "Enter" be pressed
```

Comment: You've given a pretty exhaustive answer, but you're still missing a couple of things to OP should note: 1) calls to [rand()](https://linux.die.net/man/3/rand) should be preceded by a call to "srand()" once, earlier in the program. 2) One should always save - and check - the return value from [sprintf()](https://linux.die.net/man/3/printf).  This is the only way to ensure that all the reads in the format specification actually succeeded.

Comment: @paulsm4 Thanks for your comment, really appreciated it. What about this edit, still exhaustive (I want to get better at this haha). I didn't understand what you meant the implementation of `sprintf()`, could you show how, please?

Comment: Sorry - my bad. I meant "scanf()" (same man page; different library call).  You should always check the return value of *scanf()*.  The examples you gave should each return "1" (i.e. "successfully read one item").

Comment: Like `if(scanf(" %[\n]s", str) != 1) its_an_error_do_something;` ?

Comment: Yes - exactly..

Comment: regarding: `scanf("%[^\n]s", c.name);`the `s` in the format string will cause the `scanf()` to fail, because the next character in `stdin` will be `\n`, not `s`.  Suggest removing that `s`

Comment: regarding: `srand(0);`  this will result in the same output sequence when calling `rand()`  Much better to use: `srand( (unsigned)time(NULL) );`